# Edmx model sharing with Xamarin Android project

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, entity-framework, xamarin

(sorry for bad English first)

I have ASP.NET web application project with Models/Controllers/Views folders. 
Models folder contents .edmx model file, which was created by using EntityFramework around MS SQL database.

All operations with database is realizing with stored procedures, which where converted to methods in DbContext file.

Now i want to use this models folder (especially DbContext file) in my Xamarin.Android project in android application. I want to use same methods (stored procedures in db) in the same solution with Web application.

How can i do this?

What did i try:
1) I tried to modify References file in Xamarin.Android project with adding reference to Web App. It doesn't work at all, because there was a lot of errors at compiling phase and requires a lot of additional assembly reference
2) I tried to create PCL (portable for Android) and add models or smth to this project, and then share them, but it did not work too.

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You cannot access SQL Server directly from an Andriod device

Comment: @ErikEJ I am trying to call methods from dbcontext file (whice are represents stored procedures in MS SQL server). I am not trying to access SQL Server directly. I just want to use existing .edmx model and following EF files in another android project. And i don't know how to share this dbcontext file in a correct way.

Comment: Linked files, perhaps?

Comment: @ErikEJ Sorry, but could you explain your answer and sketch out the steps to do it? I am working with Visual Studio for two weeks and still lost a bit there.